# How to improve quality and detail in faces and hair with Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, image-quality, sharpening

I would like to use this photo on a smartphone wallpaper which means cropping it to vertical and in turn losing some quality. What is the best way to improve/enhance the details in the faces and hair to make it more high quality?

[image: Cropped Image]

I use Photoshop CC

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate the layer, with the top layer selected: filter->Others->high pass

apply a low radius (you have to test, but something around 3 px should be good)

Now set the blending mode of the top layer to linera light, reduce the opacity and then use a layer mask to apply the effect only where you want.